# Page get blank when redirect from one screen to another using PHP in Tablets

Tags: javascript, php

I am using PHP and using the below line of code for redirection but the time page goes blank is there anything update or am I making any mistake please help me. This only happens in Tablets.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">
```

Comment: This is not valid PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

redirect in php

```
<?php 
header("Location: https://google.com");
die();
?>
```

or if you really want just to reload the current page .this code reload it every 5 seconds

```
<?php 
header("Refresh:10");
die();
?>
```

Comment: what is an issue with this code it's working fine in windows browsers? 

<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">

Comment: after changing your mentioned header("Location: https://testurl.com") 

getting following error

headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\chiro_kiosk\includes\views\_header.php:160) in

Comment: @AdeelZaidi There is not issue with "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">" it is a HTML way of refreshing/redirecting page while header(" ");  is PHP also about   header("Location: testurl.com")   that means it will visit "testurl.com" every 0 (Zero) miliseconds that probably the reason you seeing "error headers already sent" you need to put  die(); or exit();    after every   header(" ");   to prevent seeing this error

Comment: i just notice your previous code "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">"   on the question post has 0(Zero) timer it will refresh the page every 0 miliseconds thats probably the reason you seeing white page since it keep refreshing every 0 miliseconds so white page only